# How to center text over an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center both horizontally and vertically a text block above an image. I've reviewed other posts but they don't seem to resolve my problem.

Here's the code:

```
<body>
   <div id="top-of-page">
     <img src="images/etudes.png">
     <div id="text-block">
       <h1>Title</h1>
     </div>
   </div>

#haut-de-page {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}

#top-of-page img {
  width: 100%;
}

#text-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Even though I've set the div "text-block" position:absolute the text keeps appearing under the image.

Do you have ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
  height: max-content;
}

#text-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-of-page">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://www.mooreseal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/dummy-image-square.jpg">
    <div id="text-block">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. I just got some questions : what do the transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
align-items: center; and the z-index: 100; do I'm not entirely sure?

Comment: Align items center centers the elements within the div so in this case the text. I probably didn't need to use it some of the things in the code I was trying out some things lol but transform: translate(-50%, -50%); is centering it horizontally in the middle, and Z-Index is the layer of the div that you are targeting. Everything on the page is set default to Z-Index: 0; but if you make it Z-Index: 100 it will show on top of everything that is below Z-Index: 100;. You could even do Z-Index:1; but I just do 100 just in case.

Comment: I have a good resource for you here it explains it better https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: pls edit css part. I can't edit it right now since edit qeue is full.